# ER Diagram for User Profile and multiple Social Media Entries?

Tags: mysql, database, facebook, entity-relationship

See this table:

[image]

How would these tables relate to each other in an ER diagram (in the format 1/N --- [Relationship Name] ---- N/1)

The `USER` table contains the user `first name`, `last name`, `email`, `phone`, etc....

When the `User` registers and adds a social media entry to their profile, they have a choice with "all known" social media types, which is stored in the `SM` table.

The `SM` table contains entries like Facebook, and may contain a field for the "Facebook" logo, LinkedIn, Twitter, etc.

The user can add any amount of social media entries to their profile (at some point, I'm sure it should only be allowed to have "one" of each type of account per user, but I'm more focused on how this simpler setup is diagramed)

Thanks!

Comment: You don't really need an `__ID` field in the `USER_SM` table. Since this is a Many-to-Many relationship table, the `UniqueID` / `PK` for this table will simply be a combination of the `SM.__ID` and `USER.__ID`.

Comment: THANKS! One of those problems where the answer was too obvious to find haha. Cheers!